# Unknown mappedBy in hibernate OneToOne relationship

Tags: mysql, hibernate, dropwizard, one-to-one

This is yet another question on the unknown mappedBy exception thrown by Hibernate while create a OneToOne relationship between two objects.

From my understanding a mappedBy is required in one of the two objects to state that the tables are joined by a primary key by the second table.

This mapping declaration needs to exist on the table containing the foriegn key.

based on this , here are the two classes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "second")
public class Second implements Serializable{


    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="first_id")
    First first;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
```

---

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "first")
public class First implements Serializable{

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="first")
    Second second;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

}
```

This throws an exception

```
Unknown mappedBy in: First.second, referenced property unknown: Second.first
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you declared entity classes in `persistence.xml` ? Can you post `persistence.xml`?

Comment: http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToOne ?

Comment: I am using the dropwizard framework so I dont configure an XML

Answer (score 0):

I hadnt registered the classes with the Hibernate Bundle instance in teh application class